# How to correctly execute query in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I need to execute the `SELECT pg_database_size ('mydatabase')` query, how do I do this in Django with the Postgres DBMS?

I already tried doing the following

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
size = cursor.execute('''SELECT pg_database_size("mydatabase")''')
```

But the resulting `size` is `None`.

How do I perform this query? The intent is to return the size of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's almost right, but note that while `cursor.execute()` will execute the SQL, `cursor.fetchall()` is needed to return the result. [More info in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Try doing the following:

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT pg_database_size("mydatabase")')
    size = cursor.fetchall()
```